# Building Javascript API

Tags: javascript, api

I need to build a javascript API that can make several Ajax calls internally to perform a certain action.

I want the javascript to be referenced from my website similar to being referenced from CDN.
I am running into two issues that I badly need to resolve.

Lets say my javascript is hosted in www.api.com; js file = myapi.js
 Consumed in www.application.com

1. When I am trying to access an api (www.api.com/v1/api1) as /v1/api1 from myapi.js, it resolves the url to www.applicationl.com/v1/api1. How do I overcome this issue?
2. I need to read the cookie from www.api.com to initialize an object in myapi.js. But, reading cookie from the js file would get the cookie from www.application.com

I see that bootstrap css and JQueryUI when referenced from CDN reference the related files from their servers as relative path. How is that different?

Can anyone help?

Comment: doesnt help! if I use //v1/api1 it doesnt take me to www.api.com/v1/api1. Rather it points to the url - v1/api1

Comment: If I could use absolute URL, this question wouldnt have been there! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. URLs in JS are relative to the document that provides the host environment. You have to use  a scheme relative or absolute URI.
2. Pass the data you would store in the cookie about using the request and response bodies instead (use a structured data format such as JSON or XML for your data)

Comment: To do the request response, I need to get the API base uri. The question how to get it!? I cannot hardcode it as my service is a multitenant web server